# Find all elements that have touchstart handler attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there a way (JS pure or Jquery) to search for all elements on a page that have (as an example) a touchstart event handler attached?

I read that the $._data( $('.element')[0], 'events' ); method gets the events on a certain element. My idea so would be the inverse of that.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I try to explain what I am doing (or at least plan to do;-).
Basically I need a workaround for the iOS8+ bug concerning the missing touch events registering in iframes within homescreen (standalone) use.

So my idea was to have an overlaying div which I place above the iframe. In it I create cloned (blank) pseudo elements that trigger the touch events in place of the iframes real elements.
So I did (and this part works just fine):

```
var $frameContents = $("#my_iframe").contents();
$("#overlayer").empty(); // avoid double elements on reopening  

// example element  
var $exampleElement = $frameContents.find("#exampleElement");

$exampleElement
    .clone()
    .empty()
    .appendTo( "#overlayer" )
    .on( 'touchstart', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $exampleElement.trigger( 'click' );
    } );
```

As I said everything fine up to here.
The second part of my idea would be (instead of defining each element by myself) let the code search for all elements that make use of the touchstart event and do the procedure automatically.

Referring to your comments and answer I tried:

```
var touchElements = []; // array for all elements to be found (with touchstart events attached to them)

$.each( $frameContents, function( index, value ) {

    $(value).each(function(i) { // loop through each button
        var log = $._data( $(value).get(i), "events" ); // get the event bound on it

        if ( log.touchstart ) { // check if a particular event is bound
            touchElements.push(value); // perform the task.
        };
    } );
} );

alert(touchElements);
```

Sadly this part does not work at all because I lack in understanding this each stuff too thoroughly :-(
How can I create this array with all elements that have touchstart events on them?

Would be so cool to get some help.
Thanks so far for your ideas!

Comment: I think you will have to iterate over all the elements and check whether the handler is configured

Answer (score 0):

As you have a piece of code you can make use of that this way:

```js
$("button").on({ // here bound some events on a button element
  click: function() {
    alert("Hello")
  },
  touchstart: function() { // here is the touchstart event
    alert("World")
  }
});

// Lookup events for this particular Element
$('button').each(function(i) { // loop through each button
  var log = $._data($("button").get(i), "events"); // get the event bound on it

  if (log.touchstart) { // check if a particular event is bound
    console.log('yes touchstart is bound.'); // perform the task.
    // logs the message 4 times as touchstart event is bound on
  } // button element only not on type"submit".
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>mybtn</button>
<button>mybtn</button>
<button>mybtn</button>
<input type='submit' value="submit" />
<button>mybtn</button>
```

Comment: So I guess the answer to my question is a combination of both: your answer and the comment on my question by Arun. So I’d had to iterate over EACH element existing on the page, run the code you suggest here and then create somehow an array adding each time an element if the touchstart is bound (in your code: "yes, touchstart is bound") Oh Jesus…